# Lazy loading : Observable not subscribed

Tags: angular, rxjs, lazy-loading

In my Angular App, I have a parent component :

**console.component.html**

```
<div class="main">
  <ibe-snackbar></ibe-snackbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

routler-outlet can load two child component. One is loaded eagerly the other one is loaded with lazy loading. Here's the routes file

**console.component.routes**

```
const ConsoleRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'console', component: ConsoleComponent, data: {context : CONSOLE_CONTEXT},
    children: [
      { path: "projects", component: ProjectsListComponent, data : {context : PROJECT_CONTEXT}}, --> Loaded eagerly
      { path: "projects/:projectId/users", loadChildren: "./users/users.module#UsersModule" }, ---> Loaded laziness
      { path: '', redirectTo: "projects", pathMatch: "full" },
    ]
  }
];

export const ConsoleRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(ConsoleRoutes);
```

The snackbar component initialize an observable which will display a message on component when it will be called.

**snackbar.service.ts**

```
export class SnackbarService {
  private subject = new Subject<any>();
  constructor() { }

  showSnackbar(message, type) {
    // Treatment
    this.subject.next(snackbarInfos);
  }

  getSnackbarObservable(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**sanckbar.component.ts**

```
export class SnackbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private snackbarService: SnackbarService, private translate: TranslateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.snackbarService.getSnackbarObservable()
    .subscribe(snackbar => {
      this.snackbar = snackbar;
      this.display();
    });
  }
}
```

So the child component call the snackbar service which send the informations to the observable.

I noticed that the observable initialized in snackbar.component.ts is never subscribed (never called), when my child component is loaded with lazy loading...

However it works perfectly when the child component is load eargerly

Have you an idea why the RxJS observable is not called ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect it's because lazy loaded module has its own scope of singleton service, means there two instance of your SnackbarService. Try move the service to the highest level module like app module see if that solves the problem.

Comment: My console component was lazy loaded too (Maybe it was the problem ?). I move my snack bar component to the highest level (App) and it worked. Thank's for your answer ;)

Comment: thanks, there should be some note in the official doc  https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 1):

I see where you want to get the value after your component is loaded so instead of using the subject you should use the BehaviorSubject. It will emit the last value to the new subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem when I call a service into provider:[myService] into myLazyLoad Module if you remove the call for my works. Recommend read this [Angular 2 & RxJS: Subject.next not working in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68276680/angular-2-rxjs-subject-next-not-working-in-some-cases/69122864#69122864)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29795929)

Answer (score -1):

Lazy loading would not affect the subscription to any service or observable.
The problem would be related to the type of **Subject** you have used in the service.

I think you should be using `ReplaySubject` instead of `Subject`