# Angular 2 & RxJS: Subject.next not working in some cases

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription, behaviorsubject

I have this service (`authApiService.login()` works just fine, gets expected data):

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  private loggedIn: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(
    !this.isTokenExpired()
  );

  get isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
  }

  logout(): void {
    /* ... */
    this.loggedIn.next(false);
  }

  login(login: string, password: string): Observable<LoginResult> {
    return this.authApiService.login(login, password).pipe(
      map((result) => {
        if (result) {
          /* ... */
          this.loggedIn.next(true);
        }
        return result;
      })
    );
  }

}
```

And following component functions (`processLogin()` works just fine, tested without subscriptions):

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loggedInSub = this.authService.isLoggedIn.subscribe(
      (loggedIn: boolean) => this.processLogin(loggedIn)
    );
  }
```

After I log out from my application (calling `logout()` from service), this `.next()` actually emits false value and subscription inside component (declared in `ngOnInit()`) works. But when I call service's `login()` method, debugger shows that `this.loggedIn.next(true);` is executed, but subscription inside component does not execute provided code. I have no idea why `logout() => next(false)` works, and `login() => next(true)` doesn't. All mentioned methods without implementation are tested and work just fine. Please help!

EDIT:

Just noticed - `login() => next(true)` does not work, but page refreshing work (page behaves like "true" in subscription)

Comment: Can you make example on stackblitz?

Comment: Would it work if you replaced the entire `map` with `tap(result => result && this.loggedIn.next(true))`?

Comment: @BojanKogoj this may be a problem, because the system is really big, I'm just moving my project from Firebase backend to regular one in .NET Core

Comment: @user776686 unfortunately, not working...

Comment: As @BojanKogoj suggested ... with something like this, it really helps to have something runable (like a stackblitz) to really see what might be happening. We are (definitely!) not asking for your large application. Just a quick demo app with the method(s) that aren't working.

Comment: Do you subscribe to the result from `login()`?

Comment: @DonaldDuck yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 months (and 6 at all) I fixed it. It was only about removing AuthService from module providers. It seems like different instances were created in different modules. But I'm not an Angular expert, if anyone know how to explain it, then please try.